# App Engine ndb parallel fetch by key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm retrieving a batch of items using their keys, with something like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import model

# …
keys = [model.Key('Card', id, namespace=ns) id in ids]
cards = yield model.get_multi_async(keys)
```

The result of that in appstats is this:

[image: appstats screenshot]

The reverse-waterfall thing seems to be caused by keys being sent one by one in parallel, each in its own RPC.

My question is, is there a way to retrieve multiple objects by keys with a single RPC call? (Assuming that would speed up the overall response time of the app).

Comment: You may want to have a read of this.. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/appengine-ndb-discuss/U7JK8my5TbA/Psdf2F7sU1MJ

Comment: @lecstor it seems like putting my entities in entity groups would (more or less) solve the problem. Testing it now…

Comment: There isn't a problem here to solve - doing this is faster than fetching entities in a batch.

Comment: @NickJohnson thanks — I can't rest until I try both to see for myself, at least I know now how to do it. I assume the reason for this lies in the implementation of the HRD datastore. Is there some explanation somewhere why is this the case, or how is getting by keys implemented on a lower level?

Comment: @AttilaO. Keys in different entity groups sent in a single batch are fetched serially. By sending them in separate batches, they're all fetched in parallel.

Comment: @NickJohnson That actually explains it all. Our solution to this "speed issue" is to group entities that are *likely* to be fetched together in entity groups. We used KeyProperties in order to be able to change the relation after creating the entity, now, since we can't change the key of the entity, we'll just wipe and re-create the same entity in another entity group when we want to "move" it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting guido [response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appengine-ndb-discuss/U7JK8my5TbA/vuFL6IXggvsJ) in the thread linked by lecstor.

> You can always try issuing fewer RPCs by passing
>   `max_entity_groups_per_rpc=N` to the `get_multi_async()` call

Multiple parallel rpcs should be more efficient than a single multi-key RPC.

> The engineers responsible for the HRD implementation assure me this is more
>   efficient than issuing a single multi-key Get RPC